# Change directory to each value of list

Tags: python, weblogic

I am writing the below code:

```
connect('user', 'password', url='t3://host:1234')
domainConfig()
cd("JDBCSystemResources")
dataSources = cmo.getJDBCSystemResources()
if [len(dataSources) >0]:
    mylist = []
    for dataSource in dataSources:
        dsName = dataSource.getName()
        mylist.append(str(dsName))
        mylist_len=len(mylist)
    y=1
    while(y <= mylist_len):
            for dir in mylist:
                       cd(os.path.join(dir+'/JDBCResource/'+dir+'/JDBCResource/'+dir))
                       max_value = cmo.getMaxCapacity()
                       print dir+'='+str(max_cap)
                       cd('/')
                       y = y + 1
```

when I execute this code, it cd to only first value of the list and give this error

> EssXADS=100
>
> This Exception occurred at Sat Aug 21 08:41:53 UTC 2021.
> javax.management.AttributeNotFoundException:
> com.bea:Name=EssXADS,Location=FADomain,Type=weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.wl.JDBCConnectionPoolParamsBean,Parent=[FADomain]/JDBCSystemResources[EssXADS],Path=JDBCResource[EssXADS]/JDBCConnectionPoolParams:mds-ESS_MDS_DS
> Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):   File
> "/tmp/data_source_status_new.py.FS_bkp", line 16, in ?   File
> "", line 182, in cd   File "", line 1878, in
> raiseWLSTException WLSTException: Error cding to the MBean

Please help me to change the directory and perform the action on every value of list. I am running this on weblogic prompt.

Comment: update line 2 to cd(dir+'/somesubdir/'+dir+'/somesubdiir/'+dir) and try.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, its ending with the same error. its cding to first value of the list but not going to next iteration

Answer (score 0):

you could use the [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) function for this.
In your code it would look something like this,

```
for dir in mylist:
 cd(os.path.join(dir,"some_dir",dir,"some_dir",dir))
```

Comment: it did not help. I just changed the code to make understand what I am doing exactly. can you please check now if its not going to other directory due to domainConfig() Mbean. If the same I do something under domainRuntime() it goes fine.